# Get max values of multiple properties CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have multiple cosmosdb documents that have an entry point in an hierarchy,
I need to select the closest match based on the level values that I provide.

The query at the bottom works but I now need to select from this to return the first document with the best match. E.g

```
SELECT c.id, (MAX(p.level1Match, p.level2Match, p.level3Match, p.level4Match)) as match FROM (sub query below) p ORDER by match (Take first)
```

Sub query:

```
(SELECT  
c.id, 
(c.level1= 'level1Value' ?  1 : 0) as level1Match,
(c.level2= 'level2Value' ? 2 : 0) as level2Match,
(c.level3= 'level3Value' ? 3 : 0) as level3Match,
(c.level4= 'level4Value' ? 4 :0) as level4Match
FROM c
WHERE c.Name = 'NameValue')
```

but I cannot work out how to get this to work with CosmosDb or if this is the best approach, any help would be appreciated.

Update, as requested there would be multiple documents that look something like this

```
{
    "id" : "b2fcac67-b5ee-4646-ac77-f14db8f8fec0",
    "name" : "OrgName",
    "level1" : "Head Office",
    "level2" : "HR",
    "level2" : null,
    "level3" : null,
    "level4" : null,
    "reportDate" : dateTime,
    "notes" : "",
    "isCurrent" : true
    },
    {
    "id" : "b2fcac67-b5ee-4646-ac77-f14db8f8fec0",
    "name" : "OrgName",
    "level1" : "Head Office",
    "level2" : "HR",
    "level2" : "Another Branch",
    "level3" : "Staff",
    "level4" : null,
    "reportDate" : dateTime,
    "notes" : "",
    "isCurrent" : true
    }
```

So items can be at different levels in the hierarchy, I would pass the levels to match in as parameters.

Comment: Please show example data to help understand what you're querying against.

Comment: @NoahStahl, done

Comment: Thanks. I confess this is confusing to me. Usually when queries get complicated and opaque like this, I think there is a smell about the data model itself.